# memchr a bin file

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to look for 0x0D0A in a binary file., but strchr stops when it finds 0x00 and I don't get the right positions.

Please tell me why it's not working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

main(){
    FILE *f;
    long size;
    char *buffer;

    f = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if(f==NULL){fputs("File error",stderr); exit(1);}

    // obtain file size
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(f);
    rewind(f);

    // allocate memory to contain the whole file
    buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
    if(buffer == NULL){fputs("Memory error",stderr); exit(2);}

    // copy the file into the buffer
    if((size_t)fread(buffer,1,size,f) != size){fputs("Reading error",stderr); exit(3);}
    fclose(f);

    // get positions
    char *p;
    p = strchr(buffer, 0x0D0A);
    while(p != NULL){
        printf("found at %d\n", p-buffer-1);
        p = strchr(p+2, 0x0D0A);
    }

    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

The `if(((char*) memchr(p+1, 0x0A, size))-1 == p)` doesn't work now

```
int *pos,i=0;
char *p;
p = (char*) memchr(buffer, 0x0D, size);
while(p != NULL){
    if(((char*) memchr(p+1, 0x0A, size))-1 == p){
        pos[i++] = p-buffer-1;
        printf("found at %d\n", pos[i-1]);// check
    }
    p = (char*) memchr(p+2, 0x0D, size);
}
```

Comment: You know the reason and you ask why it's not working?

Comment: I think he's asking for a remedy to that

Comment: You might just use `mmap` on your file, and then use the solution of @Mario.

Comment: For your update: don't use memchr to check for 1 specific character, do "if (p[1] == 0x0A) { /* found */ }" as in the answer of patriiice and aix or use the answer of Mario which is simple enough to check for 2 characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use the `str...()` functions for binary data as they're meant to be used with strings only (take `memcpy()` vs. `strcpy()` as an example).

You'd just have to do a simple loop:

```
unsigned int pos = 0;

while(pos + 1 < size) // compare with +1 as we won't check the last char in the buffer
{
    if(buffer[pos] = 0x0d && buffer[pos+1] == 0x0a)
        printf("found at %d\n", pos);
    ++pos;
}
```

Also keep in mind that depending on file size you might want to not read the whole file into memory at once. As for other mistakes see aix's answer.

Answer (score 7):

Use memchr to find '\r', and then test if '\n' is the next character.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you've already explained one reason (possible embedded NULs). Another reason is that you're not adding a NUL character at the end. The third reason is that `0x0D0A` that you're giving `strchr` isn't a character.

You could use `memchr` to do *part* of the job (search for `0x0D`). If you go down this route, you'll have to check for the `0x0A` yourself.

Comment: memchr solved the first part, but in a bin file with 4 0x0D0A it returns 8 positions

Comment: I think it just look for 0x0A not for 0x0D0A

Comment: It'll search for the character you ask it to, no more, no less. It can't search for two characters at once, as explained in the last sentence of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

memchar return an adress and since you found the adress of first accourence of 0x0D and store it in p then you cannot find 0x0A or even another 0x0D at the same adress. try derefencing p and the return value of memchar to see what are they pointing at assuming you are looking for chars not thier adresses.